# Textpad not able to open Tomcat server log files

Tags: tomcat, textpad

I am using Tomcat server for my application.

When the Tomcat server is started, then the logs files are not opening in Textpad.
Textpad says "reading....." for long time but file is not opened.

If I stop the Tomcat server then the logs are opening properly in Textpad.
I am able to open the logs with other text editors like notepad, notepad++, etc

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an configuration issue? In textpad you can choose to lock files when it is edited in textpad. And if this configuration has been choosen textpad will wait because it can't put a lock on the file (depending on the writing program and its configuration).

I do not have an environment with english text available, but I'm sure you will find the corresponding setting following:

- configuration
- file (2nd entry)
- locking file during work (or similar text)